How to copy a CVariable to the heap in Kotlin/Native
I have a CVariable that was created inside of memScoped { } which means that when I return something from memScoped { }, the memory would be freed which means that I'd run into a use-after-free which is undefined behavior:
private fun chooseSwapExtent(capabilities: VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR): VkExtent2D {
    if (capabilities.currentExtent.width != UInt.MAX_VALUE) {
        return capabilities.currentExtent
    } else return memScoped {
        val width = alloc<IntVar>()
        val height = alloc<IntVar>()
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(
            vulkan.klava.glfw.window.window,
            width.ptr, height.ptr
        )
        println("GLFW framebuffer size: ${width.value}x${height.value}")

        println("GPU minImageExtent: ${capabilities.minImageExtent.width}x${capabilities.minImageExtent.height}")
        println("GPU maxImageExtent: ${capabilities.maxImageExtent.width}x${capabilities.maxImageExtent.height}")

        alloc<VkExtent2D>().also { extent ->
            extent.width = width.value.toUInt().coerceIn(
                capabilities.minImageExtent.width,
                capabilities.maxImageExtent.width
            )
            extent.height = height.value.toUInt().coerceIn(
                capabilities.minImageExtent.height,
                capabilities.maxImageExtent.height
            )
        }
    }
}

When I actually try to use this:
val extent = chooseSwapExtent(swapChainSupport.capabilities)

The values in the struct would actually be something that seems to be random instead of what was actually stored in it. It looks like it's stored on the stack and once memScoped { } leaves, it would be freed.
There's probably a way to copy by value instead of passing around pointers but for a more general use case where you need to pass things around between Kotlin and C and maintain it throughout the lifetime of the application, I'd like to know how to copy the value to the heap so that it can be used regardless of the memory lifetime where it was created.

This is a generic solution I've come up with:
inline fun <reified T : CVariable> T.onHeap() =
    nativeHeap.allocArrayOf(listOf(this)).pointed

This allocates an array that has one element of whatever you want to copy. Since we're talking about C Interop, an array with one item is basically just that one item since arrays in C is just one item after another without any headers of any sort. So in this case, the array pointer is also the pointer to the value since there is only one value.
And then it just returns the pointed value so it can be used as-is without any special conversion.
I'm not too sure if this is the best way to do it but so far it has worked well.
Example:
private fun chooseSwapExtent(capabilities: VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR): VkExtent2D {
    if (capabilities.currentExtent.width != UInt.MAX_VALUE) {
        return capabilities.currentExtent
    } else return memScoped {
        val width = alloc<IntVar>()
        val height = alloc<IntVar>()
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(
            vulkan.klava.glfw.window.window,
            width.ptr, height.ptr
        )
        println("GLFW framebuffer size: ${width.value}x${height.value}")

        println("GPU minImageExtent: ${capabilities.minImageExtent.width}x${capabilities.minImageExtent.height}")
        println("GPU maxImageExtent: ${capabilities.maxImageExtent.width}x${capabilities.maxImageExtent.height}")

        alloc<VkExtent2D>().also { extent ->
            extent.width = width.value.toUInt().coerceIn(
                capabilities.minImageExtent.width,
                capabilities.maxImageExtent.width
            )
            extent.height = height.value.toUInt().coerceIn(
                capabilities.minImageExtent.height,
                capabilities.maxImageExtent.height
            )
        }.onHeap()
    }
}

Notice the onHeap() call after }.
